# Import table into existing sqlite database android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am in a situation where the user has a sqlite database that has data that should not be tampered with at all. Essentially I want to import a table from a .csv file or something along those lines into their database without touching any of the data.

I notice that there is no library frmo what I can see that does explicitly this. My knowledge with SQLite isn't as comfortable as I'd like it to be so I'm unsure of where to go here.

Should I just read the file line per line copying the data and then inserting it into the created table? Each table will have 400 records, not too many so I figure it can't be that inefficient. My inexperience is what worries me thinking I will somehow damage the data. Hoping to prevent mistakes and liability here..

Comment: `Should I just read the file line per line copying the data and then inserting it into the created table?` It seems the correct way to do that. `what worries me thinking I will somehow damage the data` Then enclose the whole batch in a transaction. The data will be all in or nothing.

Comment: @ModularSynth My worries are with SQLOpenHelper. I wasn't sure if I would encounter some issue down the road had I needed to import tables as every User would have different data. I assumed this was bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here's one way:
```

> Create a new temporary database table without a primary key (so you can verify it before copying it.)

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE salespeopleTMP (
    id INTEGER,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    commission_rate REAL NOT NULL
);
```

> and there is existing data in the table that looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from salespeople;
1|Fred|Flinstone|10.0
2|Barney|Rubble|10.0
```

> If I now have a CSV data file named people.txt that looks like this:

```
3,John,Doe,5.0
4,Jane,Smith,5.0
```

> Import the CSV data into that temporary SQLite table

You can import the CSV data into my SQLite table with these two commands:

sqlite> `.separator ','`

sqlite> `.import people.txt salespeopleTMP`

> Use the INSERT INTO command to import the data from your temporary
>   table into your actual table

```
insert into salespeople select * from salespeopleTMP
```

> Delete your temporary table salespeopleTMP

based on and bug fixed from https://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-csv-import-data-table-primary-key

Comment: Please format this answer better. What is not code should not appear as code.